# Pandoc Markdown to Latex PDF: table merges rows in single row?

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

Consider this example for `test.md` Markdown file:

```
---
title: "Testing"
author: Bob Alice
date: July 07, 2010
geometry: margin=2cm
documentclass: extarticle
fontsize: 12pt
output: pdf_document
---

Here is a test of a table:

+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Box name | Another parameter |  The IP address |
+==========+===================+=================+
| Test 1   | random-string-01  |       10.0.0.20 |
| Test 2   | random-string-02  |       10.0.0.30 |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

If I convert this via pandoc:

```
$ pandoc --version
pandoc.exe 2.10 ...
```

... with:

```
pandoc test.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf
```

... the result is:

[image: test.pdf]

That is to say, "Test 1" and "Test 2" were compacted into a single row - even if the documentation is explicit about `grid_tables`:

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables

> Pandoc does not support grid tables with row spans or column spans. This means that neither variable numbers of columns across rows nor variable numbers of rows across columns are supported by Pandoc. All grid tables must have the same number of columns in each row, and the same number of rows in each column.

So, I can't really see how come it managed to merge these rows into one.

Is it possible to get pandoc -> latex -> pdf to keep "Test 1" and "Test 2" in each their own cell? And is it possible to get rid of the blank vertical space at the bottom of the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Grid tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-grid_tables) use explicit vertical lines to separate rows. The fact that there are line breaks in the other cells is incidental, as the contents don't fit into a single line.

Use this instead:

```
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Box name | Another parameter |  The IP address |
+==========+===================+=================+
| Test 1   | random-string-01  |       10.0.0.20 |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Test 2   | random-string-02  |       10.0.0.30 |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks - that works fine; although there is quite a bit of vertical space under each line of text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMoKq.png

Comment: The cause for this is that the IP addresses are indented by more than 4 spaces, causing pandoc to treat them as code blocks. Use `:` characters in the `=` line to indicate alignment.