# Pandoc Markdown to Latex PDF: table with alternating row colors?

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

I would like to have a table, in the (xe)latex PDF output of a Markdown document via `pandoc`, with alternating row colors - as noted here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518097/booktabs-but-with-enclosing-border-around-the-table

> ... and `xcolor` with the `table` option to add alternating row colors

So, I'm trying this `test.md`:

```
---
title: "Testing"
author: Bob Alice
date: July 13, 2010
geometry: margin=2cm
documentclass: extarticle
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes: |
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
output: pdf_document
---

Here is a test of a table:

+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Box name | Another parameter |  The IP address |
+==========+===================+=================+
| Test 1   | random-string-01  |       10.0.0.20 |
| Test 2   | random-string-02  |       10.0.0.30 |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

If I convert this via pandoc:

```
$ pandoc --version
pandoc.exe 2.10 ...
```

... with:

```
pandoc test.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf
```

... the result is:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.60 \rowcolors
```

So, apparently `xcolor` gets loaded in this setup, with other options, that clash with the `[table]` option.

Is it possible to coax `pandoc` into producing all tables in a Latex/PDF document with alternating row colors - without using custom templates?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer this question but it is a good reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83101/option-clash-for-package-xcolor

Comment: Thanks for that @user1759789 - that link did contain the solution to the problem!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the link by @user1759789 in comments, it seems that it is enough to pass the Latex document class option `table`, which then gets passed when to `xcolor` when is loaded; note that the code will still generate this error, if you leave the `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` line. So the working Markdown is this:

```
---
title: "Testing"
author: Bob Alice
date: July 13, 2010
geometry: margin=2cm
classoption: table
documentclass: extarticle
urlcolor: blue
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes: |
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{gray!25}
output: pdf_document
---

Here is a test of a table ( [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835496/) ):

+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Box name | Another parameter |  The IP address |
+==========+===================+=================+
| Test 1   | random-string-01  |       10.0.0.20 |
| Test 2   | random-string-02  |       10.0.0.30 |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+

and another grid table:

+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Box name | Another parameter |  The IP address |
+==========+===================+================:+
| Test 1   | random-string-01  | 10.0.0.20       |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Test 2   | random-string-02  | 10.0.0.30       |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------+

and pipe table:


| Box name        | Another parameter       |  The IP address |
|-----------------|-------------------------|-----------------|
| Test 1          | random-string-01        |       10.0.0.20 |
| Test 2          | random-string-02        |       10.0.0.30 |
```

... and the output is:

[image: test.pdf]